# Bean property 'trustStore' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, keystore, truststore

I'm getting the following error:

```
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'trustStore' of bean class [it.gvb.arch.connector.http.HttpClientBuilderFactory]: Bean property 'trustStore' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:1076) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:927) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:95) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:75) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1510) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
```

I need to load a truststore in my application context, ad I was trying the same way as explained in Spring [Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/security.html), so I configured my bean like this:

```
<bean id="secTrustStore" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.support.KeyStoreFactoryBean">
    <property name="password" value="${http.truststore.password:#{null}}"/>
    <property name="location" value="${http.truststore.location:#{null}}"/>
    <property name="type" value="${http.truststore.type:pkcs12}"/>
</bean>
```

Any suggestion on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not Spring's `KeyStoreFactoryBean`, the problem is that *your* `HttpClientBuilderFactory` class does not have the `trustStore` property or is missing a setter. Double-check the class.